# Problem in Laravel Middleware Auth and Verified Routing using Laravel Fortify "Register Email Verification"

Tags: laravel-8, laravel-middleware, laravel-fortify

I have successfully configured all the facilities using ***Laravel Fortify*** but I have faced a ***little problem*** in middleware routing that is I know that When we try to apply email verification we use "Auth" and "Verified" middleware to achieve it. Like...

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->middleware(['auth', 'verified']);
```

It works. But I can't go home page, it redirected me to the login page. When I remove Auth Middleware and try to go home page, it also redirected me to the login page. If I remove Verified Middleware and try to register, it redirected me to the home page with logged-in instead of to go Email Verify Message Page But the email was successfully sent.

> How to solve this problem, when an unregistered user goes to the home page and sees Login in Navigation like E-commerce Website and besides that when a user tries to register, the email has to verify and redirect to home page.